# Alternative to over by function in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    StudentName VARCHAR (50),
    StudentGender VARCHAR (50),
    StudentAge INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Sally', 'Female', 14 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Edward', 'Male', 12 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Jon', 'Male', 13 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Liana', 'Female', 10 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Ben', 'Male', 11 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Elice', 'Female', 12 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Nick', 'Male', 9 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Josh', 'Male', 12 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Liza', 'Female', 10 )
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Wick', 'Male', 15 )

go

SELECT Id, StudentName, StudentGender, StudentAge,
SUM (StudentAge) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentGender ORDER BY Id) AS RunningAgeTotal
FROM Students
```

I need the same output of the above query in sql server 2008, please help as some our clients are in sql server 2008

Comment: upvoted for providing proper sample data.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should seriously consider upgrading your SQL Server 2008 to a newer version, as it's out of extended support since last July.

That being said, assuming you can't upgrade, you can use a correlated subquery instead `SUM`:

```
SELECT Id, StudentName, StudentGender, StudentAge, (
        SELECT SUM (StudentAge)
        FROM Students As S1
        WHERE S1.Id <= S0.Id
        AND S1.StudentGender = S0.StudentGender
        GROUP BY StudentGender
        ) As RunningAgeTotal
FROM Students As S0
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the query, it work well but it not regrouping by gender.

Comment: @VenkatRaghavan Not sure what you mean, [it returns the exact same result as the query you've posted](https://rextester.com/AZBVV2852) (using sum...over).

Comment: Id StudentName StudentGender StudentAge RunningAgeTotal
1 Sally Female 14 14
4 Liana Female 10 24
6 Elice Female 12 36
9 Liza Female 10 46
10 Wick Male 15 72
7 Nick Male 9 45
8 Josh Male 12 57
5 Ben Male 11 36
2 Edward Male 12 12
3 Jon Male 13 25

But I need the output as below

Id StudentName StudentGender StudentAge RunningAgeTotal
1 Sally Female 14 14
4 Liana Female 10 24
6 Elice Female 12 36
9 Liza Female 10 46
2 Edward Male 12 12
3 Jon Male 13 25
5 Ben Male 11 36
7 Nick Male 9 45
8 Josh Male 12 57
10 Wick Male 15 72

Comment: I don't know what's the point of your last comment - but if you click the link on my last comment you'll see a rextester demo based on your sample data with both queries running and producing the same results.